# Problem with understanding the proof of Motzkin in the Proofs from the book

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation

Let $X$ be a finite set with $n\ge 3$ elements and let $A_1,...,A_m$ be proper subsets of $X$,
for which any pair of elements in $X$ is in exactly one $A_i,\, 1\le i\le m$. Then $m\ge n.$

---

Firstly some terminology:

For $x\in X$

$r_x:=$ number of $A_i$ with $x\in A_i$

$\Longrightarrow 2\le r_x < m$, and for $x\notin A_i: r_x\ge |A_i|$

The proof uses a contradiction with first expecting $m<n$.

Then it follows that $n(m-r_x)<m(n-|A_i|)$ for $x\notin A_i$

And then moving on to the following inequality which then shows the contradiciton:

$$1=\sum_{x\in X}\frac{1}{n}=\sum_{x\in X}\sum_{A_i:x\notin A_i}\frac{1}{n(m-r_x)}>\sum_{A_i}\sum_{x:x\notin A_i}\frac{1}{m(n-|A_i|)}=\sum_{A_i}\frac{1}{m}=1$$

I really cant wrap my head around the middle inequality.. can someone maybe explain why it holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality

$$\sum_{x\in X}\sum_{A_i:x\notin A_i}\frac{1}{n(m-r_x)}>\sum_{A_i}\sum_{x:x\notin A_i}\frac{1}{m(n-|A_i|)}$$

is obtained by reversing the order of summation and using the fact that $n(m-r_x)<m(n-|A_i|)$ when $x\notin A_i$. Specifically, on each side of the inequality we’re taking a sum over all pairs $\langle x,A_i\rangle$ such that $x\in X\setminus A_i$.

- On the lefthand side we fix $x\in X$ and sum one term $\frac1{n(m-r_x)}$ for each $A_i$ that does not contain $x$.
- On the righthand side we fix $A_i$ and sum one term $\frac1{m(n-|A_i|)}$ for each $x\in X\setminus A_i$.

Each $\langle x,A_i\rangle$ with $x\in X\setminus A_i$ yields a term $\frac1{n(m-r_x)}$ on the left and a term $\frac1{m(n-|A_i|)}$ on the right, and since $n(m-r_x)<m(n-|A_i|)$ for this $x$ and $A_i$, we have

$$\frac1{n(m-r_x)}>\frac1{m(n-|A_i|)}\,.$$

That’s the case for every pair $\langle x,A_i\rangle$ with $x\in X\setminus A_i$, so each term on the left is larger than the matching term on the right, and the lefthand sum is therefore larger than the righthand sum.